# Connecting to pgsql from django web app within docker-compose on elasticbeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a multi-container app on AWS elastic beanstalk, the app works and connects to my local postgresql db fine while I `docker-compose up`. But however when I deploy it on elastic beanstalk, there's an error saying

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to 
address: Name or service not known
```

I read some post saying that it's my settings.py in my app directory and that I need to set the `'HOST': 'localhost',`to`'HOST': 'db',` because that is the service the `docker-compose.yml` is looking for? So here is my`settings.py` and my `docker-compose.yml` file. Please let me know if this is right or if there seems to be any other issue.

settings.py:

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'actualnameofdb',
            'USER': 'xxx',
            'PASSWORD': '*****',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=rdeng
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=walterfedy
      - POSTGRES_DB=db1
    ports:

      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    #image: rdeng/test:latest
    build:  $PWD
    environment:
      - RDS_DB_NAME=db1
      - RDS_USERNAME=rdeng
      - RDS_HOSTNAME=db
      - RDS_PASSWORD=walterfedy
      - RDS_PORT=5432
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py makemigrations && python /code/manage.py migrate && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0$
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV POSTGRES_DB db1
ENV POSTGRES_USER rdeng
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD walterfedy

COPY  $PWD /code/

WORKDIR /code/
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt


COPY  $PWD/back.sql /code/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/back.sql


EXPOSE 8000 5432
```

Comment: Are you using RDS? or postgres in your server?

Comment: I mean in your postgres docker container?

Comment: @seuling thank you for your reply, I think i'm using postgres for my databases in my container. I got the image from the docker files and ran a script to populate it with a datadump. Do you see what is wrong for me?

Comment: OK im looking now... do you have Dockerfile?

Comment: @seuling thank you for the help! Yes i updated the post with it.

Comment: I guess that you're web container run before your postgres container all ready. In my case, I use `start.sh` and add postgres db check...

Comment: Maybe just add `restart: always` under your your web services for testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure docker to work with django and postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234559/how-to-configure-docker-to-work-with-django-and-postgres)

Comment: Hi @reddd__1 would you please show your `Dockerrun.aws.json`. Is `db` container running? `docker ps | grep 'db'`